# MySQL converting string date to date format while updating table

Tags: mysql, database, date

What is wrong with is MySQL query? It hangs without any error output!
The date field in source in VARCHR 10, I want DATE in destination table.

```
UPDATE fp_data_all t1 
INNER JOIN fp_data t2 
ON t1.apn = t2.apn 
SET t1.doc_date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(t2.doc_date, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want `date` in the destination, then just use `str_to_date()`:

```
UPDATE fp_data_all t1 INNER JOIN
       fp_data t2 
       ON t1.apn = t2.apn 
    SET t1.doc_date = STR_TO_DATE(t2.doc_date, '%m-%d-%Y');
```

If this doesn't work as expected, then perhaps some values of `doc_date` are not in the correct format.

If the query is "hanging" there are several possibilities:

- A lock on the table preventing updates.
- A very busy server and/or disk system.
- A very large table that takes a long time to update.
- Triggers on the table that extend the update time.

Also, you should have an index on `fp_data(apn)`.  This is important for the `join`.  In fact, an even better index would be `fp_data(apn, doc_date)`.

Comment: there are about 300K records, the query is run on my local machine. 2.8GHz Dual Core 2 GB ram Ubuntu+LAMP STACK

Comment: Gordon, I tried with index and still the problem is the same. I deleted the records from the source that had the date like "00-00-1900" didn't work either!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is this!

UPDATE fp_data, fp_data_all
SET fp_data_all.doc_date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(fp_data.doc_date, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE fp_data.apn = fp_data_all.apn